# Confused over ViewState / IPostback with persisting textbox values

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, webforms

**Scenario 1:**
I create a `TextBox`, `Button`, add them to the page, and Set the `TextBox`'s value **all** in the `Page`'s `OnInit` or `OnLoad` event.

When I do a postback / form post, via the `Button` click, whatever I had entered into the `TextBox` (from the browser) is persisted to the next postback / page load.

**Scenario 2:**
I create a `TextBox` and `Button` and add them to the page on the `OnInit` event.
I set the `TextBox` value on the `OnLoad` event,

When I do a postback /form post, via the `Button` click, whatever I had entered into the `TextBox` (from the browser) is not persisted, and instead the value I assigned during the `OnLoad` event is shown.

Can anyone explain what's happening here?
At a guess I would say that `ViewState` tracking is only started for the `TextBox` in the event following it being added, or its being marked 'Dirty' as soon as it is assigned in the next event (`OnLoad`), but these really are guesses!

Comment: Maybe a look at the page life cycle in asp.net may be helpful http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: I'm assuming you're assigning the value of the textbox in the OnLoad event in a if(!IsPostback) check? The OnInit event is the correct place to dynamically create controls, the viewstate loads after OnInit completes. Here's another good link regarding the page lifecycle: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24611/ASP-NET-Internals-Viewstate-and-Page-Life-Cycle

Comment: @DaveZych Thanks for the link. My question is probably more specific to TextBox's. Scenario 2 would behave like scenario 1 if the the Textbox value was assigned with an `!IsPostback` regardless, but thats doesnt give the answer to my question!

Comment: I don't think I understand your comment. The values for the textbox are loaded from the `Viewstate` during the `Page_Init` event... of course they will be overwritten by the values you set during the `Page_Load`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start by clearing up a common misconception: The value of a `TextBox` is persisted across postbacks because the browser sends the value as part of the form data in each POST, not because the value is saved in view state. **View state has nothing to do with the behavior you're seeing!**

Here are the stages of the page life cycle that are relevant to this question:

1. Raise the `Init` event.
2. Load posted form data (first attempt).
3. Raise the `Load` event.
4. Load posted form data (second attempt).

Now let's walk through each of your scenarios and see what happens when the user changes the value of the text box and clicks the button.

### Scenario 1a: Add controls and set the Text property in OnInit.

```
private TextBox textBox = new TextBox { ID = "textBox" };
private Button button = new Button { ID = "submitButton", Text = "Submit" };

protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    this.placeHolder.Controls.Add(this.textBox);
    this.placeHolder.Controls.Add(this.button);
    this.textBox.Text = "Hello";
}
```

1. *Raise the `Init` event.* The `TextBox` is added to the page and its `Text` property is set to "Hello".
2. *Load posted form data (first attempt).* The `Text` property is set to the value entered by the user.
3. *Raise the `Load` event.* Nothing happens.
4. *Load posted form data (second attempt).* Nothing happens because the first attempt to load the `Text` property succeeded.

Final result: The value entered by the user is persisted.

### Scenario 1b: Add controls and set the Text property in OnLoad.

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    this.placeHolder.Controls.Add(this.textBox);
    this.placeHolder.Controls.Add(this.button);
    this.textBox.Text = "Hello";
}
```

1. *Raise the `Init` event.* Nothing happens.
2. *Load posted form data (first attempt).* Nothing happens because the `TextBox` hasn't been added to the page yet.
3. *Raise the `Load` event.* The `TextBox` is added to the page and its `Text` property is set to "Hello".
4. *Load posted form data (second attempt).* The `Text` property is set to the value entered by the user.

Final result: The value entered by the user is persisted.

### Scenario 2: Add controls in OnInit. Set the Text property in OnLoad.

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    this.placeHolder.Controls.Add(this.textBox);
    this.placeHolder.Controls.Add(this.button);
}

protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    this.textBox.Text = "Hello";
}
```

1. *Raise the `Init` event.* The `TextBox` is added to the page.
2. *Load posted form data (first attempt).* The `Text` property is set to the value entered by the user.
3. *Raise the `Load` event.* The `Text` property is set to "Hello".
4. *Load posted form data (second attempt).* Nothing happens because the first attempt to load the `Text` property succeeded.

Final result: The value entered by the user is overwritten.

Comment: Really good explanation, thanks for taking the time. As I now understand it, the textbox class basically does (pseudo) 
`if (!PostedDataRestoredSuccessfully){ this.Text=$PostedData; PostedDataRestoredSuccessfully = true;`
}

Comment: @maxp: In fact, that logic is in the `Page` class, so the same behavior applies to all controls that support post data.

Answer (score 1):

A control's viewstate tracking is turned on at the end of the control's init event. Remember that control events occur before a page's.

PreInit is the event you should be adding dynamic controls in, however Init will work but you could see some inconsistent behavior. Load shouldn't be used -- for obvious reasons.

Always check !IsPostback when setting a control's initial values.

Answer (score 0):

Load View State occur between Init and Load, after Init and before Lod

The load view state stage only happens when the page has been posted back. During this stage, the view state data that had been saved from the previous page visit is loaded and recursively populated into the control hierarchy of the Page. It is during this stage that the view state is validated.

If you want persist your data with viewstate, you must not re-bind your data for each post

```
If(! IsPostBack)
{
   //Bind here your textbox
}
```

And use viewstate to persist

Answer (score -1):

ViewState tracking is turned on in the InitComplete event. So when you add a control on OnInit, it is not tracked by the viewstate, where as, when you add it on Page_Load, it is being tracked by the viewstate, and you can retrieve the persisted value of the textbox.

Comment: That's incorrect. Adding a control during the `Init` event is preferred, and absolutely will be tracked by the `Viewstate`. It's preferred because otherwise the control will have to play "catch-up" and run all of it's events after it is created.